# Error when altering a table column using ST_Dump

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I user `ALTER TABLE` to change a Multilinestring geometry column to a  Linestrings geometry column with this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE jalan_diy
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry(LINESTRING, 4326)
USING (ST_Dump(geom)).geom;
```

and I got an error like this...

```
ERROR: transform expression must not return a set
SQL state: 42804
```

Comment: Have you checked if this is a validation issue? Using st_makevalid().

Comment: You cannot have *set-returning* functions in `ALTER ... USING` (and several other locations in SQL) for a multitude of reasons. _If_ your *Multi/Collection* geometries your are attempting to re-type *always* have a single *LineString* as the only component, use `... USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)`. In every other case you will have to create a new table with the dumped results.

Comment: @Encomium i check it with `ST_IsValid`, everything seems ok...

Comment: do u mean multilinestring with 1 geom fix by `ST_GeometryN` and multilinestrings with n geom fix by `ST_Dump` ?? can u give me some example? i try but still doesnt work 
`ALTER TABLE jalan_diy
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry(LINESTRING, 4326)
CASE WHEN ST_NumGeometries(geom) = 1
THEN USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)
ELSE USING (ST_Dump(geom)).geom;`  AND

`ALTER TABLE jalan_diy
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE Geometry(LINESTRING, 4326)
USING (ST_Dump(geom)).geom 
WHERE ST_NumGeometries(geom) > 1;`

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer in this post
[a link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225970/how-to-adapt-a-postgis-query-to-modify-the-input-table-instead-of-creating-a-new)

sorry, i dont know that i've to create a new table(temp/not)

Comment: Please include relevant parts from the link in your answer, since links are subject to change and other users having the same problem wont be able to look into your solution.